# Авторизация и управление данными пользователя

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм, авторизация

столкнулся с задачей сделать авторизацию пользователей, потом получить данные этого пользователя

я не совсем понимаю как именно(правильно) происходит авторизация(с последующем управлением данными), но скажите, делаю ли я все правильно:

при авторизации, генерирую токен вида - `шифр(User-Agent + IP + salt + etc...)`, вешаю куки... Вроде бы все нормально, но как потом опознавать этого пользователя? как мне получить его посты по этому токену? если записывать этот токен в базу, то будет только единая авторизация, пользователь не сможет зайти с разных устройств...

**COOKIE:**

*Auth:* `6477288ea38dd982b60fc2ea75e25b78379bba28`

тогда я решил использовать сессии... устанавливаю время жизни `session cookie` больше чем обычно, меняю имя, значение... устанавливаю значения в этой сессии(имя, фамилия, уникальный ид юзера) - все это открыто, без шифрования. Значение для `session cookie` имеет вид - `random_token + '-' + шифр(User-Agent + IP + salt + etc...)` 2 часть нужна на случай если украдут куки.

**SESSION COOKIE:**

*Auth:* `blwdoIAdmWnfewAOWfvAdwd-6477288ea38dd982b60fc2ea75e25b78379bba28`

**SESSION data:**

```
Array
(
    [auth] => Array
      (
        [UID] => 321
        [NAME] => username
        [LNAME] => userlastname
      )

)
```

безопасно ли это? правильно ли? как вообще происходит авторизация, манипуляция данных на крутых сайтах, в приложениях(Android)? используют ли они сессии? почему некоторые устанавливают токен на поддомене? при каждом запросе переадресовывать юзера на поддомен и потом обратно - так что ли?